# How to get node inspect to show exceptions

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to [debug](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) my node app under Windows using:

```
node inspect myapp.js
```

Per the documentation I can issue commands like `sb(100)` to add a breakpoint at line 100, `exec` to evaluate an expression, etc.

But sometimes when I `r`un it unexpectedly outputs:

```
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

and then drops me to a `debug>` prompt with the code no longer running.  If I run normally (without `inspect`) in this case I am seeing an exception is being thrown.  How do I get the exception to show up when debugging? I would expect the exception to be printed and the debug prompt to show that I am at the line where the exception is occurring so that I can inspect the program state.

Note that I am not using remote debugging (e.g. `--inspect`).  I am looking for a solution that works at the command line and does not require me to manually insert debugger or console logging statements.  I did already try connecting via chrome://inspect but get a different issue where the debugger times out after 3 second because it thinks the port it just connected to is "busy" but that is a different question for a different day.

Comment: amazing. no comments or answers, leading me to believe it's not possible, which is just... wow